# System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations cheat sheet?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, data-annotations

Is there a cheat sheet for the .NET library System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations?

This is the library that is used for marking up ASP.NET MVC 3 Model classes.

For example:

```
 [Required]
 [MaxLength(20)]
 [Display(Name = "Asset")]
 public string AssetNumber { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public int StatusID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)

Comment: I want a condensed reference sheet to quickly glance at samples.  The MSDN documentation is a excellent source for a more detailed write up.

Comment: What more do you need, though? All attributes are performed the same way. Remove Attribute for the name, use the constructor and/or the properties after that

Comment: http://system-arts-en.blogspot.com/2014/05/entity-framework-dataannotations-cheat.html